# Delphi - ExtractFileName messes up unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I am using ExtractFileName of a WideString that equals to 'STF:宋体'.
The result is '??'.

It seems that ExtractFileName does not handle unicode well.

Is there an equivalent method for unicode?

Edit:

This is the line i use

```
NameStr := ExtractFileName(Name);
```

the types are:

```
NameStr:String;

Name:PWideChar
```

Comment: ExtractFileName works perfectly with a Unicode Delphi. Which version are you using?

Comment: Tested in Delphi XE and got `宋体` when running `ShowMessage(ExtractFileName('STF:宋体'));`

Comment: Not had any problems using ExtractFileName with Unicode file names. You do know that WideString <> UnicodeString (which is the Delphi string default)? Please show your code and especially the variable declarations, or we will just be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: The question marks make me believe you're using a non-unicode string variable somewhere along the call (you get question marks for characters that can't be represented as AnsiString). You should step throw your code (using F7 - step into) and look at the code; You're probably not calling the `ExtractFileName` you expect!

Comment: added the code and types i use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `TntSysUtils.WideExtractFileName` from [TNT](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using an old version of Delphi without support for Unicode. The solution is to upgrade Delphi.

Comment: You are correct - i am using Delphi 2006. Upgrading the version is not an option at this point (can't take the risk). Is there a way to solve this issue without upgrade?

Comment: You'll have to roll your own versions of all string manipulation routines. If there are a lot then an upgrade would be the less risky. If there are only a handful then you might be alright. You'll need to stop using string (which is AnsiString) and stick to WideString.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a home-cooked version of `ExtractFileName`, like this:

```
function ExtractFileNameW(FullPath:WideString):WideString;
var i,pos:Integer;
begin
  // Find the last path separator
  pos := -1;
  for i:=Length(FullPath) downto 1 do
    if (FullPath[i] = '/') or (FullPath[i] = '\') then
    begin
      pos := i;
      Break;
    end;
  if pos = -1 then
    Result := FullPath
  else
    begin
  Result := '';
      SetLength(Result, Length(FullPath)  - pos);
      System.Move(FullPath[pos+1], Result[1], (Length(FullPath) - pos) * SizeOf(WideChar));
    end;
end;
```

... but if you really need to deal with Unicode characters you should upgrade to XE. It really makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ExtractFileNameW(const FN: widestring): widestring;
 begin
  Result := UTF8Decode(ExtractFileName(UTF8Encode(FN)));
 end;
```